# Next.js server-side data fetching within `Suspense` boundaries not supported yet

Tags: next.js

I'm reading the Next.js docs on how to use streaming server-rendering with React 18 and there's a section on data fetching that says the following:

> Data fetching within Suspense boundaries is currently only supported on the client side. Server-side data fetching is not supported yet.

I understand that data can be fetched server-side only from pages, and the data would then be passed down to component through props.
Does this mean we can't use getServerSideProps in pages that have components wrapped in `Suspense`, or just that we can't pass down fetch data to these components?

Answer (score 0):

You can theoretically have a `Suspense` component in a page component, but it will be somewhat worthless. You won't get that page in the browser until the SSR hasn't rendered it. And when it does you'll get the full HTML, therefore having a `Suspense` does not add any value to the page component.

Because on the front-end you wait for data to come to you in order to modify the DOM, `Suspense` might bring some value, but for the SSR, I don't see any reason to implement it.

Comment: Would you use it for static pages instead?

I assumed that SSR would render the page with the fallback component and then stream the original component asynchronously, the point being to ignore the component initially to make the page interactive as quickly as possible.

Comment: @HialeahLiam You would use Suspense for data that's fetched on the client-side as it doesn't support server-side data fetching. If your app only fetches data on the server, either with SSR or SSG, there's no benefit in using Suspense yet.

Comment: Oh I understand now. I'm still a bit confused because I don't see where streaming comes into play with Suspense?
Is there streaming server rendering if in the end you're sending the same HTML and Javascript as if when you wouldn't use suspense?

Answer (score 0):

It is available with next13, app directory. Let's say we have two components, Orders and Users component

```
// fetch users
const getUsers=async ()=>{
    const res=await fetch(UserURL)
    return res.json}

const User=()=>{
 const users=getUsers()
 return (
 <> jsx here</>
 )}
```

Similarly "Orders" Component

```
 // fetch orders
const getOrders=async ()=>{
    const res=await fetch(OrderURL)
    return res.json }

const Order=()=>{
 const orders=getOrders()
 return (
 <> jsx here</>
 ) }
```

Let's say we have Admin Page and we render both components

```
import {Suspense} from "react"

const Admin=()=>{
 return(
       <>
       <Suspense  fallback=(<div>Loading Users</div>)>
            <Users/>
       </Suspense>

       <Suspense  fallback=(<div>Loading Orders</div>)>
            <Orders/>
       </Suspense>
       </>
 )}
```

Documentation shows data fetching with the new `fetch` API. I think somehow `fetch` api has to let `React Suspense` know that data fetching is complete so that `React Suspense` can render main jsx. I am not sure if other libraries do that

Another thing, in next.js app directory for each route, there is also `loading.js` file which will be automatically rendered while the main page is mounting. If `Users` component takes 1 second to fetch, and Orders component takes 2 seconds to fetch, `loading.js` content will be shown for 2 seconds till our `Admin` page is fully loaded. But with `Suspense`, after 1-second User component will be displayed, Orders component will be showing its own loading fallback till its fetching completed.